# jQuery 3 + jQuery-UI + Bootstrap 3 = ломается кнопка закрытия

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jquery-ui

Если в проекте подключить jQuery 3.2.1, jQuery-UI 1.12.1 и затем добавить Bootstrap 3.3.7, то ломается кнопка закрытия окна (она работает, но отображается не корректно):

https://jsfiddle.net/3wfuogvq/

```
$('<div id="myDlg" title="jQuery 3 + Bootstrap">jQuery ui close button is not shown but it works properly</div>').dialog();
```

Если поменять местами UI и Bootstrap, то кнопка отображается нормально.
Возможно есть какие-то ещё конфликты и не совместимости - пока не натыкался.

Кто работал с этими версиями библиотек подскажите пожалуйста как их правильно дружить?